# Make scrapy pipeline wait on another item in the same or previous pipeline

Tags: scrapy, twisted.internet, scrapy-pipeline

My problem is as follows:

I have 3 item pipelines

- one FilesPipeline that download archives
- one ArchiveUnpackerPipeline that unpacks an archive
- one SymbolicLinkerPipeline that generates symbolic links to the contents of those archives

The issue is the following:

Due to the way the website is built, I may have to generate symbolic links to the same archive from different items. If everything ran in a sequential manner it may look like this:

1. `item_1` initiates download of `archive_1`
2. `item_1` initiates unpacking of `archive_1`
3. `item_1` initiates symbolic linking of `files_1` from `archive_1`
4. `item_2` sees that `archive_1` was downloaded in the past, returns `item_1`
5. `item_2` sees that `archive_1` was unpacked in the past, returns `item_1`
6. `item_2` initiates symbolic linking of `files_2` from `archive_1`

But as the download may take a while it can happen that the same file is downloaded twice, and so on, which leads to errors.

Is there an elegant way to tackle this problem? My first guess is that it may work with a global dictionary that keeps track of the status of each download_url with states like `downloading`, `finished_downloading`, `unpacking`, `finished_unpacking` and using twisted Deferred -- but as I have never worked with twisted before I am not sure entirely.